# How do I fit angelic and demonic magic?

Tags: world-building, realism, magic-system

My magic system in my book is based on physics and real-world consequences. Fire spells will cause you to be frozen if you use them for too long. Creating stuff out of thin air will cause wormholes to appear and cause explosions. To fly in the universe you need wind spells. This is to contextualize what I'm asking since I'm still trying to work this out. How do you make a realistic version of white and black magic based on real world biology physics and psychology? The only reason I ask is because one of the characters in the story is a succubus who'll be later able to turn into angel and their magic is both black and white magic.

Comment: Hi! I think it would be good form to explicitly link to the related question you posted on worldbuilding.

Comment: I recommend against suggesting your magic system is based on physics, as this will potentially alienate any readers who enjoy both fantasy and science. Fire doesn't cause anything to freeze. "Creating stuff out of thin air" might hint at quantum physics or virtual particles but is utterly unrelated to wormholes, which don't exist in "real world" physics anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think the hallmark of a good magic system is that its **key elements that impact the story** are believable and predictable; by that, I mean that the consequences of a character using a spell are something that the reader can anticipate.

To make magic systems believable, they don't have to be based on physics, they need to be understandable by the reader. This applies only to the use of magic in the story that impacts the character arc or the plot. Miscellaneous spells that provide color to the story don't fall into this restriction. For instance, much of the magic in 'A Wizard of Earth Sea' or the Harry Potter series doesn't impact the story, but the important spells are well presented, carrying risks and difficulties that the reader can imagine.

For instance, in 'The Curious Case of Charles Dexter Ward' by H.P. Lovecraft, the author goes to pains to make it clear the dangers of communing with the dead and demons with a few cautionary letters exchanged between necromancers stressing how important preparation and concentration are, along with a line reading, "Don't call up, what you can't put down." It sets up the entire arc of the story.

For your magic system, maybe think about it thematically.  Black Magic is evil so it only causes harm and corruption. Maybe White Magic can only heal or inform. Maybe black magic injures the caster. Giving a magic system a limiting factor, like costing the caster prevents it from becoming too powerful.

I imagine you'll get more substantial answers by posting this question on Worldbuilding@SE.